# How to setup ModelMapper for nested to different nested?

Tags: java, spring, modelmapper

Flight object has a property like this:

```
@JsonProperty("OriginLocation")
private Location originLocation;
```

Location object looks like this:

```
@JsonProperty("lat")
private double latitude;
@JsonProperty("lon")
private double longitude;
```

I'm mapping to FlightDto where the property looks like this (NOTE: FlightDto moves 5 or so properties from Flight into LocationDto -- these all map auto-magically except for lat/long):

```
private LocationDto origin;
```

LocationDto looks like this:

```
private CoordinatesDto coordinates;
```

CoordinatesDto looks like this:

```
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
```

So... all properties are mapping correctly except for lat/long. Mapping should be:

```
FlightDto.getOrigin().setCoordinates(new CoordinatesDto(Flight.getOriginLocation().getLatitude(),
                             Flight.getOriginLocation().getLongitude());
```

There are other fields in FlightDto.getOrigin() that are somehow mapped correctly automatically.

I tried doing:

```
    modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Flight, FlightDto>() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            map().getOrigin().setCoordinates(new CoordinatesDto(source.getOriginLocation().getLatitude(),
                                                                    source.getOriginLocation().getLongitude()));
//              map().getDestination().setCoordinates(new CoordinatesDto(source.getDestinationLocation().getLatitude(),
//                                                                       source.getDestinationLocation().getLongitude()));

    }
});
```

But that actually crashes on startup:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at org.xxx.yyy.flights.models.Location$ByteBuddy$NcO8GjcN.getLongitude(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:na]
>       at org.xxx.yyy.config.ModelMapperConfig$2.configure(ModelMapperConfig.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
>       at org.modelmapper.PropertyMap.configure(PropertyMap.java:389) ~[modelmapper-2.3.5.jar:na]

I don't get why getLatitude() works, but getLongitude() doesn't for one thing... but lets say I comment out the getLongitude() and hardcode 1 in there... it seems like the setters only get called once at startup rather for each record.

I also saw some examples using TypeMap, but I can't see how I can map from 1 nested level to 2 nested levels since the LocationDto is getting created and populated correctly, but LocationDto.Coordinates is not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two issues here, see below code & comments in it:

```
// When you have different field names you should tell it to ModelMapper like this
mm.createTypeMap(Flight.class, FlightDto.class).addMapping(Flight::getOriginLocation,
    FlightDto::setOrigin);

// And when you do not have 'clear' association or mapping is not in the `same 
// level` mapping can not be guessed so you need to tell it explicitly like 
// (this is something near to what you tried already)
mm.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Location, LocationDto>() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        map().getCoordinates().setLatitude(source.getLatitude());
        map().getCoordinates().setLongitude(source.getLongitude());
    }
});
```

After telling this (these both) - assuming I understood your model/dto structure correctly - `ModelMapper` is able to make mapping.